# How to add java custom or string object to DAO model object at runtime?

Tags: java, spring

I need to add new String object to Array of custom type object, ServiceOrderEntity in this case. I know that this kind of breaks `ServiceOrderEntity` integrity but I have to access this field from jsp. What is the best way to do it?

**DAO class:**

```
...

SQLQuery localSQLQuery = localSession.createSQLQuery(query).addEntity(ServiceOrderEntity.class);
localList = localSQLQuery.list();
Iterator itr =  localList.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()){
        String field = "some value";
        itr.next().append( field  ); // something like that maybe....
     }
 return to Service class
    ...
```

**Service class**

```
...
List list = perform DAO request
model.addAttribute("serviceOrderList", localList);
....
```

---

**UPDATE**

I have all models generated by Hibernate and I don't want to touch them. I need to add to custom object, in this case `ServiceOrderEntity` or find workaround. I think I can make copy of it and append new field to it (using Dozer)? New fields is result of other complex subqueries.

**List of ServiceOrderEntity objects at runtime:**

---

```
-list
--[0]model.ServiceOrderEntity@d826d3c7
---createdBy = {....}
---serviceRequestFK{java.Lang.Integer}     // << this one
--[1]
....
etc
```

---

I need to get `name` using **serviceRequestFK** in `ServiceOrderEntity`. As long as java doesn't allow `hot fix` (to add custom filed to already created object) I need to find a way to pass to JSP the `name` field as well. What is the right way?
I really  don't want to include DAO mathod requests from jsp...
Create separate list of names?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java does not allow mix-ins (aka monkey-patching) you'll have to:

- Add the field to the base entity.
- Return a sub-class that includes this field.

If you'd like to add the field so that the Service class can do its job, then fair enough. However, if the new field is part of the payload in/out then consider instead for that particular service then consider:

- Making use-case specific payloads for each service call.
- Map the results of these onto your reusable object model. (You can use something like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) for this).

The rationale behind this suggestion is to follow the principles of contract-first development.

- Your model will be more general purpose, and thus reusable. You can add reusable behaviors to your model classes. Your services will use these behaviors to orchestrate process. (As opposed to having 'anaemic' entitites).
- Your service payloads can remain relatively stable over time. So changes to your model won't effect all of your service subscribers. (aka "don't spill your guts").